# Joining 4 Tables together and checking where totals do not match

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables act,up, pos_act, pos_up
In this example, let's say I have customer ID and Amount columns as

act.cust_id, up.cust_id, act.amount, up.amount
pos_up.cID, pos_act.cID, pos_up.amount_, pos_act.amount_

```
       act    

| cust_id | amount |
|:-------:|:------:|
|   6789  |  30.00 |
|   9876  |  25.00 |

       pos_act

|   cID   | amount_|
|:-------:|:------:|
|   6789  |  30.00 |
|   9876  |  24.99 |


----------------------------------------

        up

| cust_id | amount |
|:-------:|:------:|
|   1234  |  10.00 |
|   2345  |  75.00 |


        pos_up

|   cID   | amount_|
|:-------:|:------:|
|   1234  |   9.99 |
|   2345  |  75.00 |
```

Now With this, I want to compare where amounts do not match all in one table.
So in this example 2345 matches in up but in act 1234 does not match.

Then the results should be

```
    All Unmatched  

| cust_id | Table  |
|:-------:|:------:|
|   9876  |  Act   |
|   1234  |  Up    |
```

I tried with unions but cant seem to get that working

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select cID, amount FROM  act as a
    union select cID, amount FROM up as b
) as v
LEFT JOIN 
(select CID, amount_ FROM pos_up as c
 UNION select CID, amount_ from pos_act as d
 ) as r
 WHERE a.amount != d.amount_
```

I also tried with left joins but it just shows me all results.  I only want ones that do not match.  custid is a unique ID and may appear multiple times.

Comment: What did you try? show us your query.

Comment: @Alex just added it a few sec ago

Comment: @VLRoyrenn That is correct.  So I want to see which is an error.  The act table or up table is the master and is always right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use `UNION` in a wrong place

```
SELECT cID, amount, 'act' as `table`
FROM  act as a
LEFT JOIN pos_act as pa
ON a.cust_id = pa.
 WHERE a.amount != pa.amount_
UNION ALL
SELECT cID, amount, 'up'
FROM  up as u
LEFT JOIN pos_up as pu
ON u.cust_id = pu.cID
WHERE u.amount != pu.amount_
```

Comment: Ahhh. So close.  THank you sir.